# The path '/App_GlobalResources/' maps to a directory outside this application, which is not supported

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2003

The file that generates this error looks like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>  
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load()
    {
        Response.Write("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
```

The web application doesn't use resource files and does not contain a folder called 'App_GlobalResources'.

The system:

- Windows Server 2003 R2
- IIS 6.0
- ASP.NET 2.0

I found a [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8fb4fc5-97b8-4335-969e-b9a35ccc853e/appglobalresources-maps-to-a-directory-outside-this-application-which-is-not-supported?forum=aspinstallandsetup) that apparently works for many users as you can see in the [forum topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8fb4fc5-97b8-4335-969e-b9a35ccc853e/appglobalresources-maps-to-a-directory-outside-this-application-which-is-not-supported?forum=aspinstallandsetup) and also in [some](https://web.archive.org/web/20141015172700/http://technical.davidunderwood.org/?p=140) [blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170504001328/http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk:80/the-path-appnameapp_globalresources-maps-to-a-directory-outside-this-application-which-is-not-supported). But it does not work for me for me. Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-creating the website in the IIS. Now everything works as expected! I have absolutely no clue, what the problem was!

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt about 7 times, this did it for me!

Comment: I actually just restarted the website on the web server and this seemed to work.

Comment: Close and re-open Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

For me, I suspect this was caused because I had the same project, from 2 different branches open in Visual Studio at the same time.    Building in one of them caused the error in the other.   It has to do w/ how it automatically registers sites w/ IIS(Express).
Closes Visual Studio & reopening does the trick.